# react-router-dom error when refreshing page with id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, router, react-router-dom

I'm developing a project using `React/Redux` and `Node.js`.

I added `react-router-dom` as a dependency into my project and configured the router like this:

```
import ...

const Router = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={components.main}/>
      <Route path='/caseDetail/:id' component={components.caseDetail}/>
      <Route component={components.notFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Router
```

And setup my webpack like this

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const env = require('./src/env.js')
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  assets: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
}

const common = {
  entry: [PATHS.app],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } }],
        include: /flexboxgrid/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /flexboxgrid/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'web', 'browserify', 'main', 'style']
  }
}

if (TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET) {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          use: ['source-map-loader'],
          enforce: 'pre'
        }
      ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: PATHS.build,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
      https: true,
      host: env.host,
      port: env.port,
      overlay: {
        errors: true
      },
      watchOptions: {
        watch: true
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'assets/style.css' }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: PATHS.app + '/index.html',
        inject: 'body'
      })
    ],
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
  })
}

if (TARGET === 'production') {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: "'production'"
        }
      })
    ],
    output: {
      path: '/build',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
  })
}
```

**My problem is**

When I call this route `/caseDetail/1` it works by using Link:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/caseDetail/` + caseStudy.id }}>
```

**BUT**, if I call **directly by the browser**, like https://localhost:3000/caseDetail/1

It fails, I get this message on console

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:3000/caseDetail/assets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
0:12 GET https://localhost:3000/caseDetail/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
0:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:3000/caseDetail/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

---

### **SOLVED**

**How to fix.** Thanks to @soroush-chehresa

I added into my `router` file, the BrowserRouter like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { components } from './loader'

const Router = () => (
  <main>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={components.main}/>
        <Route exact path='/caseDetail' component={components.caseDetail}/>
        <Route path='/caseDetail/:id' component={components.caseDetail}/>
        <Route component={components.notFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </main>
)

export default Router
```

And also added into my `webpack.config.js` on `output`

```
  publicPath: '/'
```

---

Comment: post your whole webpack config, it is better for people to have a look

Comment: Ok @PlayMa256. Done, the question is edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) wrap `Router` with `ConnectedRouter`:

```
  import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
  import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

  const Router = () => (
    <main>
      <ConnectedRouter history={createBrowserHistory()}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={components.main}/>
          <Route path='/caseDetail/:id' component= {components.caseDetail}/>
         <Route component={components.notFound}/>
       </Switch>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </main>
  );
```

Otherwise if you are using [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) wrap `Router` with `BrowserRouter`:

```
  import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

  const Router = () => (
    <main>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={components.main}/>
          <Route path='/caseDetail/:id' component={components.caseDetail}/>
          <Route component={components.notFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </main>
  );
```

Comment: Hi @soroush chehresa . Thanks for you answer. I wrapped with `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` but still don't work. Is there anything I need to setup after adding it?

Comment: @ViniciusPaldês Please try changing Webpack dev server content base to `contentBase: './'`

Comment: @ViniciusPaldês Try to add `publicPath: '/'` to the output of Webpack config. https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Comment: @ViniciusPaldês Don't mention it! ;)